# Background image won't display in div but will in body tag

Tags: html, css

I went to my friend's house to see how my webpage displays on other resolutions, but found that the background image didn't reach the sides. So, I went home and did some research and was told that instead of having my background image in the body tag, I should create a div inside of the body tag before the `container` div and it would work.

This did work for one of my designs but not in the other - the code was exactly the same, but the images weren't.

I tried adding `position:absolute` in my CSS and it does show, but it has a strange white border along the top and left hand side.

How can I resolve this issue?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}

.background{
    background:url('images/background.png')no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

Comment: What are the dimensions for images/background.png ?

Comment: Do you think you can link to the webpage you're referring to or put an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can take a closer look?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite enough information to really give you a good answer... but the white line on the top and left of the page sound like the natural margin appended to the body tag.  If you add this to your css it should remove that:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
}
```

Also, the background image "reaching the sides" will be primarily dependent on the image's dimensions relative to the viewing screen resolution and browser size.  These factors are out of your control so be cautious where you're using an image in the background of your designs.

Comment: Just to expand a little bit - OP, you may want to learn about CSS Resets. If used properly, they will strip a lot of browsers' default margins, paddings, etc. so you have a more consistent starting point.

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick replys and the edit of my question,when i said new to html and css i mean 1 week into it so sorry about the format of my question im abit confussed with this site,im not at my computer at the moment so i cant try your answers but if been thinking today that maybe my background image should be large enough to cover all resolutions? and i thought i added this to my question but the background will display when i add it to the css tag of body, but will not if i move it to .background. i havnt heard of this jsfiddle before but il have a look tonight,thanks heaps

Comment: hey was also thinking,please let me know if it is unapropaite of me but i can give you guys a link to a mediafire download so you can check it out even give some comments to how im doing?